# Realtime OS alternatives that run Windows apps?

Tags: realtime

I have an Microsoft .NET application that needs to be sped up, so it can have more deterministic round trip response times to incoming TCP/IP internet packets.

Are there any realtime builds of Windows, or realtime OS's that will run Microsoft .NET code?

Comment: I have deep doubts that running a .NET app on a non-MS OS is going to improve performance.

Comment: In the context of an internet-connected, ethernet-networked machine handling TCP/IP packets, is Windows' lack of *determinism* your real issue? That is, are you simply looking for a way to increase average response times instead?

Comment: Just looking to increase the average response times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The obvious OS to look at is [Windows Embedded,](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/windows-embedded.aspx) which can give you soft real-time, or hard (depending on your app), but I don't know offhand how good its support for .Net is.  [There are certainly versions of Win Embedded that have *some* support for .Net](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/evaluate/windows-embedded-server-key-features.aspx) but the devil is going to be in the details.

Added later: another alternative - if you're a masochist - is that you might be able to port your app to run on a [PLC using these libraries.](http://www.ingeardrivers.com/netlogix/netlogix.htm#)

Comment: Good answer - I think Windows embedded may be the easiest way to move forward.

Answer (score 3):

You could look into RTX from IntervalZero: http://www.intervalzero.com/rtx.htm

It's a commercial realtime extension to Windows that may give you the determinism you're seeking.

Is this a financial trading app?

Answer (score 2):

You can run [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) on Linux. Mono is an "open source, cross-platform, implementation of C# and the CLR that is binary compatible with Microsoft.NET"

Comment: Mono performance is far from adequate in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a realtime expert, but you could try to run your app under Windows CE.

I don't know if .Net is available, but worth checking.

Comment: Win Embedded is the new CE, literally: http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/evaluate/windows-embedded-compact-7.aspx

Comment: Good to know. I've not been using Microsoft products for some time now, my sources are a bit outdated ;)

Comment: Thats good to know.